# About Set of formulas with numbering put in a tables which reported (It's hard to come up with a name)?

Tags: tables, equations, pdftex

I want to achieve a table like this:

[image]

I tried as:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Optimization Problem Formalization Equations}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \hline
        \begin{equation}
            max(profit - expenditure)
        \end{equation}
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But it reporte a error: you can't use `\eqno in restricted horizontal mode?

Comment: Please always provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here, there is no document class or preamble

Comment: Why exactly are you placing numbered equations inside a floating table? That seems to be asking for trouble.

Comment: As has already been requested, please complete your code. E.g. from the preamble we learn more about what you use and perhaps miss using. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have re-edited my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you *not* employ a `tabular` environment. Instead, use (i) a couple of `\hrule` directives to draw lines that span the width of a column and (b) `multline` and `alignat` display math environments that are provided by the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
% for '\DeclareMathOperator*' macro and 'multline' and 'alignat' environments:
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{table} % just for this example

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Optimization Problem Formalization Equations}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \hrule % draw a full-width horizontal line 
    \begin{multline}
    \argmin_{x\in\Omega} \biggl(\, \sum_{h\in H} 
    \Bigl[ W^{\mathrm{cpu}}_h\sum_{f\in s} r_{rv} x_{\!fh}
         + W^{\min}_h y_h \Bigr] \\
         + \sum_{i\in L} W_{\mathrm{net}}\sum_f b^s_v x_{\!fh} 
    \biggl)
    \end{multline} 
    subject to:
    \begin{alignat}{2}
    \sum_{f\in s} r_{rv}x_{\!fh} &\le y_h a_{rh} & \qquad 
        & \forall \ h\in H,\ r\in R \\
    \sum_{f\in s} b^s_vx_{\!fh}  &\le g_ib_i 
       && \forall \ i\in L \\
    \sum_{h\in H}\sum_{f\in s} l_v x_{\!fh} +
    \sum_{i\in L}\sum_{f\in s} p^s_i x_{\!fh} &\le l^s
       && \forall \ h\in H,\ i\in L
    \end{alignat} 
    \hrule % draw another full-width horizontal line
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But if that floating table moves, how do you get around the problem of proper numbering (assuming that there are other numbered equations in the man text)?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. To be honest, I can't say I understand why the OP wants to place the equation and the three inequalities in a `table` environment. It may well be preferable to place the material in a non-floating `minipage` environment and to use a `\tableof` instruction to create the equivalent of a `table`-type caption. Hopefully, the OP will weigh in with some more information.

Comment: Thank you Mico, It's works!